# Convert nested for loop into RxJS transformed Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

The following function is working, however it's an absolute hack as I'm taking `.value` from a `BehaviorSubject` when it would be best to maintain this as an observable.

**Current Code**

```
  get ActiveBikeFilters(): any {
    const updatedFilters = this.bikesService._bikeFilterSource.value;
    const activeArray = [];

    for (let filterGroup of updatedFilters) {
      for (let childFilter of filterGroup.filters) {
        if (childFilter.checked) {
          activeArray.push(childFilter);
        }
      };
    }
    return activeArray;
  }
```

Whilst this works, I would prefer if something like this (not working / psudo code).

**Proposed Sample Code**

```
get ActiveBikeFilters(): Observable<BikeFilter[]> {
  return this.bikeService._bikeFilterSource.pipe(
    map(filterGrp => {
      return filterGrp.map((filterGrp2) => {
        return filterGrp2.filters.filter((filter) => {
          if (filter.checked) { return filter }
        })
      })
    }),
    toArray()
  )
}
```

For reference the data which is going to be transforming / filtering looks like this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "title": "Difficulty",
        "filters": [
            {
                "name": "Easy",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Medium",
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "title": "Filter 2 Title",
        "filters": [
            {
                "name": "Filter 1",
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Filter 2",
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of JS **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** as follows:

```ts
get ActiveBikeFilters() {
  let processed = this.bikeService._bikeFilterSource.pipe(
    map(filterGroup => {
      return filterGroup.reduce((a, b) => {
        b.filters.filter(i => i.checked ? a.push(i) : true)
        return a;
      }, []);
    })
  )
  return processed;
}
```

Here's a **[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8ena4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

```
this.bikesService._bikeFilterSource.subscribe(updatedFilters =>{
updatedFilters.map(filterGrp => {..})
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jens, although I don't think that this answers my question. I want this observable to be forming the transformation for all those which subscribe to it. You're proposing that the transformation is done after subscription which would lead to a lot of replication in my case.

Comment: Ok so moverthe map into your service that has the behaviorsubject. When you have transformed the data, call next on the behaviorsubject. bs.next(tranformeddata). Any one subscribing on the behaviorsubject will get the altered data

Comment: There are different consumers of the BehaviorSubject so I have to perform this transformation / filtering on the observable rather than the source. The other consumers need the original data or a different transform.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
return this.bikeService._bikeFilterSource.pipe(
  map(filterGrp => {
    return filterGroup.filter(u => u.filters.some(t => t.checked === true));
  })
)
```